# Freddy Krueger's Lullaby

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge

> 1, 2.
>
> Freddy is drawing eyeballs.
>
> 2½, 3.
>
> One iris got bigger.
>
> 3½, 4.
>
> The other got bigger.
>
> 5, 6.
>
> Aura passes from and to irises.
>
> **[NUMBERS REDACTED]**
>
> Never sleep again.

What is Freddy singing about?

Subtle Hint:

> Start with dots.

Moderate Hint:

> The numbers are redacted because currently, numbers end by 6.

Decisive Hint:

> The "aura" may seem like equipotentials between heterogeneously charged conductors:
>
>  [image: equipotentials]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is singing about

> The [separation axioms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom)

*1, 2. Freddy is drawing eyeballs.*

> In $T_2$ spaces, or **Hausdorff spaces**, every two distinct points can be seperated by open sets. It is commonly depicted by the following diagram: [image: Hausdorff space]

*2½, 3. One iris got bigger.*

> In $T_3$ spaces, or **regular spaces**, every disjoint closed set and point can be seperated by open sets. It is commonly depicted by the following diagram:[image: regular space]

*3½, 4. The other got bigger.*

> In $T_4$ spaces, or **normal spaces**, every two disjoint closed sets can be seperated by open sets. It is commonly depicted by the following diagram:[image: normal space]

*5, 6. Aura passes from and to irises.*

> In $T_6$ spaces, or **perfectly normal spaces**, for every two disjoint closed sets, there exists a **continuous** function whose return value is 0 on and only on one closed set and 1 on and only on the other closed set. (Hence the decisive hint)

Comment: Great! This probably should be the accepted answer (regarding the existence of $T_{2\frac12}$ and $T_{3\frac12}$).

Comment: @trolley813 Well, it is the OP self-answering - I'd very much hope this *was* correct! :)

Comment: For those of us too slow to make the connection ourselves, can you add an explanation of how Freddy Krueger fits in?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he is singing about

> [Cassini ovals?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval) (or some similar curves)

Reasoning

> The equation of the oval is $(x^2+y^2)^2-2a^2(x^2-y^2)+a^4=b^4$. When the $c = \dfrac b a$ ratio increases, the oval initially looks like "eyeballs" (2 separate loops, indeed starting with 2 dots when $c=0$), with increasing "irides", then (when $c=1$) the halves are fusing with each other (it will be Bernoulli lemniscate - an 8-shaped curve), allowing the "aura" to pass between them, and next (when $c>1$) turning into single peanut-shaped (later, when $c>\sqrt2$, an oval-shaped) curve.

However

> this answer bears absolutely no connection with [A Nightmare on Elm Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Nightmare_on_Elm_Street_(franchise)) franchise, and it probably has to have one (since Freddy Krueger is the protagonist name, and [Never Sleep Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Sleep_Again:_The_Elm_Street_Legacy) is a documentary film that chronicles the entire franchise, and the number of installments in the main series is 6 at the moment (currently numbers end by 6!)).

Comment: Ha, nice and creative guess, but not what I intended. I intended some other branch of math. You should consider why there are numbers like 2 1/2.

Comment: Hint: I didn't intend much connection to the franchise.

Comment: As your answer was the only one, I gave you the bounty.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Thanks! It's a pity that nobody gave a better answer.