# A Lovely Riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, poetry

> Even though I'm closed in me, I love you.
>
> I am entirely in you, even though I'm closed.
>
> When I'm onto something, it's still me.
>
> If it's you one by one, we're together.
>
> No matter how I multiply, it's still me.
>
> No matter how you multiply, it's still you.
>
> If I am broken, I still love you.
>
> So that we could find a point to fix me back.

What are we?

Subtle Hint:

> I am after a common word. You are after a mathematician.

Moderate Hint:

> The line of numbers is you, and also a broken me.

Decisive Hint:

> [Freddy is still drawing eyeballs.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/92235/62436)

Comment: I was thinking the answer might be rot13(erny naq vzntvanel (1 naq v) be svavgr naq vasvavgr) but I have difficulty trying to form an explanation.

Comment: @David I'm afraid those are not the answer. Should consider the moderate hint.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> zero and one.

I am entirely in you, even though I'm closed.

> Zero makes one when it's added to one.

When I'm onto something, it's still me.

> Zero by another number makes zero.

If it's you one by one, we're together.

> A bit contrived, but one divided into one makes one (one one) and 1+0=1.

No matter how I multiply, it's still me.

> Zero always makes zero when it's multiplied by itself.

No matter how you multiply, it's still you.

> Ditto for one.

If I am broken, I still love you.

So that we could find a point to fix me back.

> If zero is divided into a number, it's still zero.

Comment: Nice interpretion, but "we" are more advanced concepts. Hint: rot13("Jr" ner frgf bs cbvagf.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a closed poset (partially ordered set) connected to its subset by a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)?

**Explanation:**

*Even though I'm closed in me, I love you.*

> **love** could mean the bijective relationship between these two sets in this context

*I am entirely in you, even though I'm closed.*

> This can be a subset referring to its superset; both are **[closed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set)**

*When I'm onto something, it's still me.*

> **onto** is a [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) relation

*If it's you one by one, we're together.*

> This could mean **one-to-one**, an [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) relation

*No matter how I multiply, it's still me.*

> This could refer to a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) under a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Orders_on_the_Cartesian_product_of_totally_ordered_sets)

*No matter how you multiply, it's still you.*

> The superset of the poset referred here also follows the above property

*If I am broken, I still love you.*
*So that we could find a point to fix me back.*

> This could refer to a transitive property that could connect two sets once they are split, although I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Nice interpretion. Hint: "I" and "You" mean different notions.